# Asp.net Menu displaying diffrent menu items depending on access level

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create an asp menu for a website. The site will have 2 levels of user Master users (which will have more options) and Sub users which will have limited menu options.

I was wonder does anyone knows if a way to hide menu items?  I've tried google but I can't really find much.

Here's the Asp code

```
<asp:Menu id="MainMenu" runat="server" StaticDisplayLevels="1" Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Setup" Value="">
            <asp:MenuItem ID="DepoAccount" Text="Depo Account Details" Value="" NavigateUrl="~/AccountManagment.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="User Accounts" Value="" NavigateUrl="~/ImplantParameters.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Actions" Value="">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="View Consignments" Value="" NavigateUrl="~/Consignements.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Add Consignments" Value="" NavigateUrl="~/Consignements.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Utitlies" Value="">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Export" Value="" NavigateUrl="~/ImplantParameters.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Reports" Value="">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Manifest" Value="" NavigateUrl="~/ImplantParameters.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

I have worked out how to hide the whole menu when the user is not logged in 
    MainMenu.Visible = false

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using standard ASP.Net authentication and membership?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [ASP.NET's Security Trimming feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428.aspx).

You should move your static menu items into an XML SiteMap file, and set `EnableSecurityTrimming` on the sitemap to true.